# Why my jQuery empty doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="submit();">launch</button>
<button type="button" onclick="clear();">clear</button>


<div>
    Result:<br>
    <div id="result">
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function clear() {
        $('#result').empty()
    }

    function submit() {
        $('#result').append('<div>xxxxx</div>')
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`Launch` button works well but `clear` doesn't. I run `$('#result').empty()` in console, it clear the div as expected.

You may debug my code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oe7huw4q/).

Comment: I checked out your fiddle.. That's totally bizarre. I stuck a console.log in clear() and it's never getting called..

Comment: Rename the function `clear()` to something else. Than it will work.

Comment: `clear` is a reserved word, rename it to something else

Comment: Dang.. Don't everyone answer at once. 5 answers within a minute!

Comment: @mjohnsonengr Everyones running for upvotes and accepted answers :P

Comment: @C0dekid.php that's fine, but you were definitely the first here with the info on clear() being taken!!

Comment: @mjohnsonengr I know, I was about to post the answer, but then this post exploded and everybody took the shine.

Comment: Try this code:
<button id="submit" type="button">launch</button> <button id="clear" type="button">clear</button> <script> $(document).ready(function(){ $("#clear").click(function(){ $('#result').empty(); }); $("#submit").click(function(){ $('#result').append('<div>xxxxxxxx</div>') }); }); </script>

Comment: I wrote a code. (https://jsfiddle.net/c8h9mq5f/2/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calling `clear()` in an inline handler is actually calling something else called `document.clear()`, and so your function is never called.

This is because in an inline handler, `document` is in scope before `window` and your `clear` function is in the global scope, which is `window` for browsers.

You can change the function name to something else

```
<button type="button" onclick="myClear();">clear</button>

function myClear() {
    $('#result').empty()
}
```

Alternatively I would prefer to avoid inline handlers and also avoid polluting the global scope.

```
$(function(){
    function clear() {
        $('#result').empty();
    }

    $('.clear').click(function(){
        clear();
    });
});
```

Comment: `window.clear` has to be called if it works as supposed, since the global object is window, not document.

Comment: I Agree that, https://jsfiddle.net/oe7huw4q/16/

Answer (score 2):

It's because clear is calling the function `document.clear()` which comes first in the considered scope that is inline HTML call.

Try to rename your function it to anything else.

Answer (score 1):

`clear` is a reserved word, rename it to something else

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your .empty() is working. The problem here is clear() function is not getting called. I tried changing clear() to clear1() and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just set it using

`$('.textboxElement').val("");`

instead of clear. I'm not sure why your clear isn't working, but this is another way of doing it. Maybe your method name is being picked up? Try naming it to 'foo'

Comment: `.val()` only works with form elements, not with dividers and other static elements other than form elements.

Comment: @C0dekid.php I would have expected it to work with textboxes full stop...

Comment: @Anonymouse yes, as you say it works with textboxes, not with plain text. `val()` means `value` wich form inputs/textboxes has.

Comment: @C0dekid.php Oh right, apologies I didn't know that. Guess I learn something new every day :-)

Comment: It's ok ^^. We are here to learn right? :) @Anonymouse

Comment: @C0dekid.php so we are :-).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your function name. "Clear" is already defined as document.clear so it is not hitting your code. Rename your function to something like clearContent.